# How to make linter show more messages?

Tags: visual-studio-code, docstring, linter

i've just setup default pylint linter in vscode but i do not get for example messages about docstrings. Maybe i missing also some other notifications from linter.
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/python#_linting

[Screnshoot from vscode documentation showing linter message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rcRDl.png)

Where can i chose which messages to enable and which to disable? I've tried looking at settings without success.

Answer (score 1):

Well, i found solution.
Have to add args in **Settings > Python › Linting: Pylint Args**
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/linting#_default-pylint-rules

For now I enabled all messages

```
--enable=all
```

Will experiment later